# varbinary(max) error in SQL

Tags: sql, image, oracle

I want to use a column that contains images in it. I've tried this code

```
create table books
(
   book_id number(4),
   title varchar2 (50),
   ISBN varchar2(20), 
   author varchar2(40),
   publisher varchar2(20),
   released number(4),
   image varbinary(max),
   constraint booksPK primary key (book_id),
   constraint booksFK foreign key (subject_id) references subject(subject_id)
);
```

and I got this error:

> Error at Command Line:29 Column:16
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

please help me with this...

Comment: As far as I know, Oracle doesn't have `varbinary(Max)` - that's a (Microsoft) **SQL Server** data type. Look into your Oracle documentation for what the equivalent datatype in Oracle would be

Comment: For oracle use `LONG RAW` instead of `varbinary(max)`

Comment: @NagarajS: the `LONG` (and `LONG RAW`)  has been deprecated for nearly 20 years now. Don't use it. You should use the `BLOB` data type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your valuable comment..

Answer (score 0):

`varbinary` isn't an Oracle data type. You should be using a [binary large object (BLOB)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882%5f01/server.112/e26088/sql%5felements001.htm#sthref199). A comment suggested `long raw`, but BLOBs [have fewer restrictions and should be used instead](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882%5f01/server.112/e26088/sql%5felements001.htm#sthref180).